# Is there a way to count the number of times each individual Facebook Friend has liked your Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Iam trying get the number of times each individual liked my particular post.

It seems that it is possible to get the overall like count of a page.

But I dont need the overall like count. I want in specific data of a user who liked my posts.

I tried these links
[How can I get fan page likes count using graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569567/how-can-i-get-fan-page-likes-count-using-graph-api)
[Getting the Facebook like/share count for a given URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728279/getting-the-facebook-like-share-count-for-a-given-url)
[How to get Facebook likes count for a Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629819/how-to-get-facebook-likes-count-for-a-facebook-page)

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to do a little bit more here than just tell us what you “need”.

Comment: No, that is not really possible. Each of your friends would have to sign in to your app and grant it permission to read their likes, and you would need to have valid individual user tokens available for all of them each time you want to request this data, because _“A User or Page can only query their own likes. Other Users' or Pages' likes are unavailable due to privacy concerns.”_ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/likes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just writing the answer which is mentioned in the comment. Because that's the answer.

> No, that is not really possible. Each of your friends would have to
>   sign in to your app and grant it permission to read their likes, and
>   you would need to have valid individual user tokens available for all
>   of them each time you want to request this data, because “A User or
>   Page can only query their own likes. Other Users' or Pages' likes are
>   unavailable due to privacy concerns.”
>   developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/